# How to remove an Adobe 'upgrade'?

Tags: upgrade, macos, adobe

I accidentally installed an upgrade of Adobe Acrobat Pro 7 to Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.

(I had the Adobe Pro 7 for Windows and was sold the upgrade without being told that I had to separately buy the base version for Mac)

To be clear : I don't have Adobe 7 on my Mac but ran the upgrade to Adobe Acrobat Pro 11.

I get the error

> The serial number you provided is valid, but a qualifying product could not be found on this computer.

This of course makes sense.

I then tried to install the *Trial* version of Mac Adobe Acrobat Pro 11, but when I go to start that program, I get the same message.

I want to remove the 'upgrade' info on the Mac so that when I run the trial version, I don't get that error message.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it.

I moved the /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Slcache and Slstore into a backups folder.

Then I ran the installer again.

Running the uninstaller did not remove these files before - that's why we kept getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe offers a standalone cleaner tool which will remove all traces of an installation, even if the installation has been broken in some way.  Download [the cleaner](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html) and run it, and it will remove the installation.

Comment: This link is unusable as it is for Windows. Anybody know how to remove it on *Mac*? My "uninstaller" is greyed out.

Comment: I solved it. I moved the /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Slcache and Slstore into a backups folder. Then I ran the installer again. Running the uninstaller did not remove these files before - that's why we kept getting the error.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Could you take a second to place your solution as an answer to this question (that is, instead of in the comments) so that people searching for this same issue in the future can find the solution more easily?